# How to create .hbs for a component in non CLI mode

Tags: ember.js

> I'm not using **Ember-CLI**

Im creating many components at a time in my `script` and some may be `block` and some not. I cannot create separate files for each components as the array to create components may change. I need to check whether the component is `block` or not, to `yield` its content and render using that content.

> **Application.js**

```
App[componentArr[i].name + "Component"] = Ember.Component.extend({
            tagName: componentArr[i].tag,
            init: function () { },
            didReceiveAttrs: function () { },
            willRender: function () { },
            didInsertElement: function () {
                //i will render the logic here.
                //need to check block params if yes {{yield}} that and render 
                //if no just render.
            },
            didRender: function () { }
        });
```

I can create a `<script>` tag for each component and append it in the `body`. but that is proper when the `array` got more than 100 items.

I need to do this in this type not by ember-CLI as i cannot loop and create components there.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: It would be helpful to see a use case for this.

Comment: @sheriffderek when i render something like`{{my-comp1}}` if it is in the array then i will render appropriate elements and plugin